# How to overtake the limit of NICs in virtualization softs?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, network-adapter

I want to connect unlimited number of NIC to a mikrotik virtual machine but all virtualization softwares has limit to the number of NICs so, is there a soft that doesn't have limit? if there isn't,which soft has the biggest number of allowed NIC ? And how many NIC does MIKROTIK support ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by unlimited. Countably infinite? Well, maybe. But anything above an aleph-naught number of NICs is pushing it. Does the number of NICs you want to connect fit into naive set theory, or do you want a [Zermelo-theory-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory) number of NICs?

Comment: @ParthianShot i could not understand all of your comment
what i'm asking is how to connect more than let's say 20 NIC